# make me idempotent

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

$T_n$ be the full transformation semigroup on $X_n= \{1, 2, \cdots , n\}$.

$D_r =\{\alpha \in T_n: |im(\alpha)|=r\}$.

$E(D_r)$ is the set of all idempotents of semigroup $T_n$.

$support(\alpha)=\{x: x\alpha\neq x\}$

We know that $\alpha \in T_n$ is idempotent $\iff$ $x\alpha=x$ for all $x\in im(\alpha)$.

I wonder product of idempotents. For example;
$\alpha =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
1 & 2 & 2 &  1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
3 & 4 & 3 &  4
\end{pmatrix} \in E(D_2)$, but $\alpha\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &  4 \\
3 & 4 & 4 &  3
\end{pmatrix}$ is not idempotent.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $\alpha_0, \alpha_1\cdots, \alpha_k\in E(D_r)$ and $support(\alpha_i)\cap support(\alpha_j)=\emptyset, 0\leq i\neq j\leq k $.

Under which condition the product $\alpha_0\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_k$ becomes idempotent ?

Comment: No further condition is needed, I believe. Also, I don't see why do you need to introduce $D_r$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე OP gives a counter example.

Comment: You need some "orthogonality" condition (something like: $\beta$ moves the support of $\alpha$ to its complement). Disjointness of supports does not affect much whether the product of idempotents is again an idempotent or not. In fact if you just write down what it means for $\alpha\beta$ to be an idempotent, that is $\alpha\beta\alpha\beta=\alpha\beta$, you get the condition you need.

Comment: The question is similar to the question of when the product of two projections of a vector space is again a projection.

Comment: @user43326 Oh I see thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Do you also want the product to have rank r?

Comment: @ Benjamin Steinberg No, It is not important. Actually, I think $\alpha_0\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_k$ is idempotent when $Im(\alpha_0\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_k)$ is representative set of kernel partition. But, I need more explanatory answer.